# Chart.js smooth draw line animation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make Chart.js line graph to draw line from left to right smoothly. I want alson icon at the end of line.

So far I was able to make line, but transition is very harsh. It is really basic way, just adding new datapoints to graph. Could somebody please help me to fix it?

Thank you

here is codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwYGrp?editors=0010

code:

```
const datam = [510, 13357, 19950, 26679, 32514, 37720, 44487, 50596, 56095, 50000, 40670]

var noneimg = new Image();

noneimg.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png'
var sun = new Image();
sun.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/yDYW1I7.png';
function animation (u) {

    function animatePart(u) {
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(datam[u]);
        Chart.pluginService.register({
            afterUpdate: function(chart) {
                if (u>0 && u <datam.length) {
                          myChart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[u-1]._model.pointStyle = noneimg;

                }
        myChart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[u]._model.pointStyle = sun;

    }
});        
myChart.update();
        }
    for (let i = 0; i<=datam.length; i++) {
        (function() {
        setTimeout(function () { animatePart(i); }, 200+ ( i * 580 ));
    })()}

    }


var ctx = document.getElementById("line_chart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017" ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'xxxx xx',
            radius: 0.7,
            fill: '#FFFFFF',
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
            borderColor: 'dodgerblue',
            borderWidth: 4,
        },{
        label: 'xxxx',
        fill: '#FFFFFF',
        radius: 0.7,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: 'indianred',
        borderColor: 'indianred',
        borderWidth: 5

    }]
},
options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'xxx',
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontFamily: "open sans",
                    fontColor: 'black',
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                },
                legend: {
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: 'black',
                        fontSize: 16,
                }},
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    titleFontColor: 'white',
                    titleFontSize: 16,
                    bodyFontSize: 13,
                    bodyFontColor: 'white',
                    bodySpacing: 3,
                    yPadding: 8,
                    borderColor: 'black',
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                },
                animation: {
                        duration: 1600,
                        numSteps: 10,
                        easing: "easeInQuad",
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: 'black',
                            fontSize: 16,
                        },
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: false,
                            labelString: 'xxx'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 70000,
                            beginAtZero: false,
                            fontColor: 'black',
                            fontSize: 16,
                        },
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: false,
                            labelString: 'xx'
                        }
                    }]
                },
            }
})

animation()
```

Comment: I believe chart.js doesn't support animating the drawing of a line between two points, only animating the scaling of a chart, such as if more points are added. You would probably have to interpolate the intermediate points and add them manually to create a more granular animation, or it might be possible to write a plugin.